# Pre-process y column in a sklearn pipeline before classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

As part of a sklearn pipeline, I'd like to bin my response variable into a variable with k ordinal categories and then do classification on these categories. I found `KBinsDiscretizer` which seems to perform this transformation but it seems it does only work on feature columns, not on the target column.

**Reproducible example**

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston


data = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['target'] = data['target']
binarizer_col_y = make_column_transformer(
    [sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal'), ['target']], 
    remainder = 'passthrough'
)
pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [
    ('preprocess', binarizer_col_y),
    ('ols', LinearRegression())
])
pipeline.fit(df[data['feature_names']], df['target'])
```

This errors with

```
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'target'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

... 
[ another key error for 'target']
```

I also found `sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor` to transform the response (but I want to do classification) and that I can write my own transformers, but they apparently ony [modify X, not y](https://sklearn-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html).

Can anyone tell me how to modify y in a pre-processing step prior to classification as part of a pipeline?

**Why inside the pipeline?**

The idea is to move as many transformations into the pipeline as possible, reducing boilerplate code, avoiding data leaks plus simplifying model deployment (e.g. as services like Databricks model registry can deploy a sklearn model with pre-processing expected to happen inside the model).

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because target is not available because the transformation is applied only to the X, and not y.
Sklearn pipeline does not support transforming target y in the way you tried to write it.

However, there is a [sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) which can wrap model and can be provided with instructions how to transform target.

Warning, it is not well supported and I found many issues when trying to work with it on a real project. Maybe you want to have manual target transformation steps.

Here is a little demo that might work for you.

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor


data = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"], columns=data["feature_names"])

X = df[data["feature_names"]]
y = data["target"]

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        (
            "ols",
            TransformedTargetRegressor(
                LinearRegression(),
                transformer=sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(
                    n_bins=3, encode="ordinal"
                ),
            ),
        )
    ]
)
pipeline.fit(X, y)
pipeline.predict(X)
```

Or a more readable snippet that shows how you create target transformer

```py
model = LinearRegression()
kbins = sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode="ordinal")
ttr = TransformedTargetRegressor(model, transformer=kbins)
```